# Iterating through an external list of values inside a LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq

**Backgrounds**

I have been working extensively with LINQ, I have a LINQ statement which I am looking to Modify in order to give me the ability to create a List of objects.

**Problem**

I currently have a LINQ statement that I am using to give me a results which I am binding to my data-models in the LINQ statement.  However, my last property inside of my data-model is a list of bools, but in order to get my bool values I need to iterate through a list of properties and get the bool values or each property in a seperate list.

**Code**

```
class GroupDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Permissions { get; set; }
    public List<string> GroupsUsers { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   RRApplication app = new RRApplication();
   List<GroupDetails> collectionOfGroups = new List<GroupDetails>();
   List<RRAccessRightType> Listofpermissions = new List<RRAccessRightType>() { RRAccessRightType.artAccountAllowChange, RRAccessRightType.artAccountMapping };
   RRProtectionSetup securitySetup = app.Protection;
   foreach(RRGlobalGroup group in securitySetup.Groups)
   {
                RRGlobalAssignedUsers usersAssignedCollection = group.AssignedUsers;
                GroupDetails groupDetail = new GroupDetails();
                groupDetail.Permissions = new List<bool>();
                groupDetail.GroupsUsers = new List<string>();                    
                groupDetail.Name = group.Name;
                groupDetail.Description = group.Description;
                foreach (RRGlobalAssignedUser user in usersAssignedCollection)
                {
                    groupDetail.GroupsUsers.Add(user.UserId);
                }
                for (int counter = 0; counter < Listofpermissions.Count; counter++)
                {
                    groupDetail.Permissions.Add(group.AccessRights[Listofpermissions[counter]]);
                }
                collectionOfGroups.Add(groupDetail);
   }
}
```

**LINQ Statement**

```
List<GroupDetails> groupUsers = app.Protection.Groups.Cast<RRGlobalGroup>()
      .Select(a => new GroupDetails {
           Name = a.Name,
           Description = a.Description,
           GroupsUsers = a.AssignedUsers.Cast<RRGlobalAssignedUser>()
               .Select(b => b.UserId).ToList(),
           Permissions = a.AccessRights[Listofpermissions[0]]}).ToList();
```

**desired Output**

```
  Name :  group1
  Description : DevGroup1
  GroupsUsers :["1234","5678"]
  Permissions:[true, false]
```

**Appendix**

As you may see the current LINQ statement will give me all the results up to the list of Users and the value of the first index in my Listofpermissions list. 
However, I am looking to iterate through another list to get the values of permission as my long handed code on the top does.

Comment: Ok.. What problem you are facing with this code? Can you share some sample input data and expected output?

Comment: I would like to iterate through my list of List<CWAccessRightType> listtest which hold two properties.  With this said I would like to put iterate through them in my LINQ statement Permission = a.AccessRights[*listtest*]

Comment: The data model you have posted isn't complete. Your query is using many more custom types. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I am using a thirds party proprietary SDK which is based on COM so I am unable to provide you with CWAccessRightType, CWAccessRightType.  I apologize, ultimately I am just trying to find a way to iterate through my listtest and hand each value to my a.AccessRights[] function inside of my LINQ statement.

Comment: You should use a trick Unix uses since 1970.  For permissions, it uses a 9 bit number where first three bits are system privileges,  next three bits Group privileges, and finally 3 bits for User privileges : RWXRWXRWX.  Now you have one Short 16 that you can enumerate through instead of separate properties.

Comment: @EasyE - It appears that `CWAccessRightType` is `public enum CWAccessRightType { Read, Write }`. That's not too hard to provide. But you've ignored the rest of your types. You should take the time to make a compilable example of your code. If I can run your code then I can answer your question. If it can't be run you miss out on a lot of good answers.

Comment: So you want to iterate a list, what is stopping you? I don't see what the issue here is.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey I went ahead and clarified my question to fully express what I am looking to do.  I wrote it out long handed to include the full logic flow which I am trying to cover with a linq statement.

Comment: @Magnus I am uncertain how to actually get it done, I have updated my question to clarify my question.

Comment: I think we still need some sample Input to get your desired Output, and what does `[[0]]` mean? in your LINQ?

Comment: @NetMage hey I really do not have much else to provide I tried to show a working example of a long handed approach.  The [0] is index zero of List<RRAccessRightType> Listofpermissions.  If you look at my long handed example it is the third and final for loop that iterates through that list and passes the value to AccessRights[].

Comment: @EasyE - When I copy and paste your code into a console app I get the following unknown types: `RRApplication`, `RRAccessRightType`, `RRProtectionSetup`, `RRGlobalGroup`, and `RRGlobalAssignedUsers`. I've asked for a [mcve] so that I can run your code - that means I should be able to copy, paste, and run your code.

Comment: i don't believe there is any valid C# syntax for `[[0]]`.

Comment: @netMage you are right corrected that.  All I am doing is grabbing the first index of that list.  I would like to iterate through that list inside the LINQ statement, instead of only grabbing the first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is helpful if you use the same lambda variable names as your looping code. This should gather all the `Permissions` together.

```
List<GroupDetails> groupUsers = app.Protection.Groups.Cast<RRGlobalGroup>()
      .Select(group => new GroupDetails {
          Name = group.Name,
          Description = group.Description,
          GroupsUsers = group.AssignedUsers.Cast<RRGlobalAssignedUser>()
               .Select(user => user.UserId).ToList(),
          Permissions = Listofpermissions.Select(count => group.AccessRights[count]).ToList()
      }).ToList();
```